# Can I hide a subform in notes designer from specific set of users?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Can I hide a subform in notes designer from restricted people using a field in the main form?

I have a field in my main form which has a bunch of email ID generated on computed for display. I only want my subform to be visible to those bunch of usernames.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You can chose to do a computed subform, 
In Designer,
First Open a Form
Then on the menu bar go to Create>Resource>Insert Subform>Insert Subform Based on Formula.

Then you can use a formula to choose to display a subform or not.

Comment: When i go to Create -> i see Design  -> then Subform    .... i do not see an option like Create>Resource>Insert Subform>Insert Subform Based on Formula ?  I am using IBM Lotus Domino Designer 8.5

Comment: You have to have a form open to see menu Create>Resource>Insert Subform (not the list of forms)

Comment: Hiding elements on a page is part of the scope that pushes me to xPages. Its so easy to hide anything on the page.